# Reason for using small sampling resistors in voltage measurement circuits

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, transformer, inductor, voltage-measurement

[image]
The above schematic is of the [ZMPT101B](http://5nrorwxhmqqijik.leadongcdn.com/attachment/kjilKBmoioSRqlkqjoipSR7ww7fgzb73m/ZMPT101B-specification.pdf) module (current type voltage transformer) collected from [Arduino Forum](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/warning-about-zmpt101b-voltage-sensor-modules-with-active-output/693258). All of the modules available in the market use a similar type of circuit having two stages of the amplifiers. Why no one uses a higher value of sampling resistor and get rid of those amplifiers? I assume a high value of the sampling resistor may create an error.

[image]
I did a proteus simulation (although simulation is not an acceptable reference), which shows a 50 Hz sine wave of almost 1 volt at the output created by a large sampling resistor. What is the disadvantage of this kind of connection?

Comment: Current transformer are specified for a specific load: you are correct it would create an error. It's an impedance matching thing.

Comment: On the last page of the datasheet, there's an equation describing the input-output relation. If the sampling resistor is constant, why have they kept it as a variable parameter in the equation?

Answer (score 1):

The transformer is specified to operate within the specified ratings and parameters when there is a specified sampling resistor as load impedance.

If you remove it or use say 1k resistor, you are using the part outside of the rated operating conditions, so none of the specification listed in the datasheet applies any more and operation is not guaranteed.